# Mocking `Rails.logger` in the RSpec tests for my Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubygems

I'm writing a Ruby gem, and below is the implementation of how I create a new `Logger`.

My gem may or may not be used inside of Rails, so it tries to use `Rails.logger` IF one exists.

```
require 'logger'

module MyLoggeer
  def logger
    @logger ||= rails_logger || Logger.new($stdout)
  end

  def rails_logger
    if defined?(::Rails) && ::Rails.respond_to?(:logger) && !::Rails.logger.nil?
      ::Rails.logger
    else
      nil
    end
  end
end
```

My gem does not have `Rails` defined anywhere as a constant. If I wanted to test the above logic with RSpec, is there a way for me to -

1. Define a mock `Rails` object
2. Have it respond to a `logger` method?

I suppose I could define a dummy class inside my spec files, but I was hoping there was a way to easily mock / stub this out instead.

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than doing all this magic, why not just expose a logger configuration like `GemName.logger=` and then the user can set it to whatever he wants including a Rails logger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With RSpec mocks you can use a [`double`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/basics/test-doubles) (as in stunt double) to create a stand in for any object.

You then use `allow` to allow the double to receive messages and `expect` to set method expectations.

```
let(:logger) do
  instance_double("Logger")
end

let(:rails) do
  double("Rails")
end

before do
  allow(rails).to receive(:logger).and_return(logger)
  stub_const("Rails", rails)
end
```

You can also use [instance doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles/using-an-instance-double) and [class doubles](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles/using-a-class-double) to create [doubles of existing classes](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-9/docs/verifying-doubles) - this will verify that you only call methods that actually exist on the class you are doubling.

`stub_const` will stub the value of a constant for the duration of an example.

Comment: `stub_const` is clever. I would rather return a StringIO logger instead of an instance double like `Logger.new(StringIO.new)` so you can later access the logged output.